# complete the res type in sdf

Tags: pdb, peptide-shaker

I use the diffdock ([link to diffdock on github](https://github.com/gcorso/DiffDock)) to dock a peptide with protein and this tool give me a ligand in sdf file format. I traslate this ligand sdf format file to a pdb format file and find the pdbfile lack res information. I wonder if tools/code can automaticly complete this file. I need the UNK become the residue types like pdb.This my error pdb file（this structure is a peptide）[image]
[image]

```
HETATM    1  C   UNK     0       9.797  22.501  -6.484  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    2  C   UNK     0      10.366  21.086  -6.446  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    3  O   UNK     0       9.550  20.218  -7.135  0.00  0.00           O 
HETATM    4  N   UNK     0      11.710  21.084  -6.978  0.00  0.00           N 
HETATM    5  C   UNK     0      11.793  20.201  -8.123  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    6  C   UNK     0      11.151  20.760  -9.346  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    7  C   UNK     0      11.586  20.031 -10.581  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    8  C   UNK     0      13.000  20.308 -10.986  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM    9  C   UNK     0      13.397  19.716 -12.309  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM   10  N   UNK     0      12.636  18.523 -12.633  0.00  0.00           N 
HETATM   11  C   UNK     0      11.861  18.392 -13.830  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM   12  O   UNK     0      11.837  19.364 -14.611  0.00  0.00           O 
HETATM   13  C   UNK     0      11.148  17.131 -14.065  0.00  0.00           C 
HETATM   14  C   UNK     0      11.800  16.246 -15.085  0.00  0.00           C
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. We cannot use them: we can't copy, we can't search. Also, this makes the post heavier for people with slow connections. Instead, copy/paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: open babel add correct res type to pdb when you feed peptide sdf file, use http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Cheminformatics/FormatConverter/index.html and https://www.litemol.org/Viewer/ to check it out –

Answer (score 1):

An SDF file lacks residue information, including atom name.
Although for the latter, the `molFileAlias` atomic property is frequently used.

### Adding residue info

There are several ways to do this, such as in RDKit ([blog post](https://blog.matteoferla.com/2020/03/atom-names-purely-in-rdkit.html)):

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

from typing import List

with Chem.SDMolSupplier('.sdf') as mol_store:
     mols: List[Chem.Mol] = list(mol_store)

mol: Chem.Mol
for mol in mols:
    atom: Chem.Atom
    for i, atom in enumerate(mol.GetAtoms()):
        info = AllChem.AtomPDBResidueInfo(atomName=f'ATM{i}',
                                          residueName='LIG',
                                          residueNumber=1, 
                                          chainId='X')
        atom.SetMonomerInfo(info)   

mol: Chem.Mol
for mol in mols:
    name: str = mol.GetProp('_Name')
    Chem.MolToPDBFile(mol, f'{name}.pdb')
```

Notes:

- Atom names do have somewhat of a standard format, C1, C2, C3. I am being lazy in the above. If your ligand is present in the RCSB PDB, it will have a chemical component info on the PDB: [example](https://www.rcsb.org/ligand/CFF) and it is often imperative to obey the atom names and atom index from there.
- PyMOL or pymol2 module can also add PDB information, therein the residue index is not an integer but a string as it combines w/ insertion code.
- In some tools, you lose the bond order, but if you have a SDF and not a PDB, then you are safe. But if you have a reference it's easy to fix.

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
template: Chem.Mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('')
AllChem.AssignBondOrdersFromTemplate(template, mol)
```

Comment: it seem c++ language which i'm not good at, can you provied a python language? the code you provided make error in my pycharm.

Comment: It's _the_ compchem module in Python. It runs on PyBind11 C++, so pycharm incorrectly does not like the methods not receiving the instance. #noqa will keep it quiet. I did write the code in the SO editor so I cannot guarantee it runs bug-free.
`from typing import List` is the only thing missing as far as I can tell.